# Short story, domed refuges

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

In this post-apocalyptic short story, a small group of people are returning from a (failed) effort to save one outpost.

They cross a snowy wasteland to find that the nearest domed refuge has also ceased functioning and are forced to stretch their supplies and physical resources to reach a farther afield one.

The story ends with them barely reaching their goal to find a warm and civilized society inside the refuge. I believe hot cocoa features in the final scene.

Comment: I didn't remember the cocoa, I remembered the sandwiches.

Comment: I didn't remember the snowy part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The story is ["The Long Rain"](http://esl-bits.net/ESL.English.Listening.Short.Stories/The.Long.Rain/default.html) by Ray Bradbury.

Excerpt from the end of the story:

> He stood before the yellow door. The printed letters over it said THE SUN DOME. He put his numb hand up to feel it. Then he twisted the doorknob and stumbled in.
>
> He stood for a moment looking about. Behind him the rain whirled at the door. Ahead of him, upon a low table, stood a silver pot of hot chocolate, steaming, and a cup, full, with a marshmallow in it. And beside that, on another tray, stood thick sandwiches of rich chicken meat and fresh-cut tomatoes and green onions.

Comment: You guys are awesome. I have a teenager who has heard a muddled version of this from me for the last decade. Now I can get down my copy of The Illustrated Man from my bookshelf before she gets home from school