# Looking for a sci-fi book or story about a man who is going crazy because the rain won't stop

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a story about "raindrops and how he's going crazy because the rain won't stop".

I read this back in the '80s.

I would love to read it again if I can find out the title of this book/story.

Comment: Hi Melodie, and welcome to Sci-Fi and Fantasy SE! Please, take a look [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for guidelines on how to ask a good story-ID question. As it is now, it doesn't contain enough detail.

Comment: Also, which part of this is sci-fi?

Comment: @Gallifreian - OP has stated in the title that it's a sci-fi book. Also, *neverending rain* is not normal, unless you live in Cumbria.

Comment: @Valorum  -  or Venus. I see your point.

Answer (score 12):

It is possibly [The Long Rain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_Rain)

> "The Long Rain" is a short story by science fiction author Ray
>   Bradbury. This story was originally published in 1950 as
>   "Death-by-Rain" in the magazine Planet Stories, and then in the
>   collection The Illustrated Man. The story tells of four men who have
>   crashed on a planet where it is always raining. As they try to reach
>   the safety of the Sun Domes, they end up being driven insane by the
>   endless rains.
>
> The story was republished in several collections and was incorporated
>   into a film also titled The Illustrated Man.

Comment: If it is, this question is a [duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52788/short-story-domed-refuges/52804#52804)

Answer (score 8):

Could you be referring to Rob McKenna (from the fourth book in the Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy trilogy)? The rain  isn't making him insane, but it's certainly made him depressed.

> *And as he drove on, the rainclouds dragged down the sky after him, for, though he did not know it, Rob McKenna was a Rain God. All he knew was that his working days were miserable and he had a succession of lousy holidays. All the clouds knew was that they loved him and wanted to be near him, to cherish him, and to water him.*