# What is the name / author of the book where the protagonist lives on a planet where it is a forest and rains all the time?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I know this is a little vague, but it's been a long time since I read the book. If I remember correctly, the guys world is a forest and it rains all of the time. It's science fiction and the main character is a young guy. I read it in English in the early 80s. By today's standards it was a short novel, probably less then 130 pages.

On further reflection, I seem to recall the author may have written about Saturn - anybody remember any stories about rainforests on Saturn?

Comment: Can you recall anything else?  A disproportionate share of science fiction protagonists are “young guys,” and rainy jungle worlds are not uncommon in science fiction. I’d be surprised if this didn’t match hundreds of works, at least.

Comment: By "book," do you mean it was a full-length novel? When/what year did you read it? What language was it in?

Comment: I read it in the early '80s. By today's standards it was a short novel, probably less then 130 pages. In English

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is Ray Bradbury's short story ["The Long Rain"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/52804/19561). Can you confirm or deny this is what you're looking for?

Comment: @SQB - I’m not sure we should try to guess on such a broad question (that’s why I closed it). I do suspect that a short story is one of the works that will *not* fit, since they mentioned a novel.

Comment: @Adamant well, yes and no. I usually wouldn't, but that story is one of the better known examples of this trope and a confirmation by the querant would make it an easy duplicate.

Comment: @SQB - that's not it. I did some more digging on google and "The word for world is forest" by Ursula K. Le Guin looks promising, but I can't tell if there was rain.

Comment: @SQB et al. I figured it out. How do I note this? Thanks to your prompting I did some further hunting and found it - "All Summer in a Day" by Ray Bradbury. My recollection was way off. Itsy bitsy short story.

Comment: @decuser great that you found it! We'll now probably close this question as a duplicate, since that's question already has been answered a couple of times, but please don't take this as a rejection, because it's not.

Comment: before the space probes in the early 1960s one of the standard depictions of Venus in science fiction was a rain forest with a lot of rain. And there  are lots of other jungle planets in science fiction.